# From where can I download the source code of the original kernel developed by Linus Torvalds?

Tags: kernel, source-code

The question might seem a bit not related to ubuntu. Please forgive me for this.

As the subject says I want to download the source code of the first ever kernel developed. I have read that it was developed Linus Torvalds.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You should ask this on the linux forums. You are more likely to get a answer http://www.linuxforums.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[kernel.org](http://kernel.org) should have all of the previous versions available, at least since they were being kept in source control.  I'm not sure if it's the very first release, but their site has linux kernel 0.01 (with a timestamp from 1993) available here:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/